# Cabal failing to install vector-space package

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I try to install the spacepart package using cabal install it tries to compile a dependency vector-space but when vector-space tries to compile a module it exports "Data.LinearMap" I get the error "Not in scope type constructor or class "HasTrie". After I did some digging HasTrie is a class exported by the MemoTrie package. Thing is I have MemoTrie installed and MemoTrie exports "HasTrie". What is wrong here? 
Also this stack overflow post doesnt help so this isnt a duplicate question: [Haskell package vector-space fails at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397892/haskell-package-vector-space-fails-at-compile-time)
-Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from browsing on Hackage, `spacepart` is fixed to use a *very* old version of `vector-space` (0.5.*), and that version's `Data.LinearMap` contains the suspicious import line

```
import Data.MemoTrie      ((:->:)(..))
```

which simply *doesn't* import `HasTrie`.  My guess is that at some time in the past, this actually worked, because `(:->:)` is a data family defined inside `HasTrie`, but that GHC has since been changed so it doesn't.

*Possible* dirty fix: I note that until 0.5.2, it simply says

```
import Data.MemoTrie
```

I just tried installing with

```
cabal install spacepart vector-space-0.5.2
```

and it seemed to work.

Comment: Yes this fix worked I also sent an email to the maintainer to update the packages accordingly :)